# AppCompatActivity cause CustomView onConfigurationChanged method not called

Tags: java, android

Last week it was work, but after I do some modify it's not work(I forgot which modify). So I build a new project to test it, can't find the reason so far.

Here is the demo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private boolean isChange = false;
private Button mChangeBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mChangeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.d("MainActivity", newConfig.toString());
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == orientation) {
        mChangeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        mChangeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
}

public void screenChange(View view) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "screenChange");
    if (!isChange) {
        isChange = true;
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    } else {
        isChange = false;
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.test.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/change"
    android:text="Change"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="screenChange"/>

<com.test.Test
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</com.test.Test>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test extends LinearLayout {
public Test(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.d("Test", newConfig.toString());
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == orientation) {
        setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
}
```

Now, when click the button of 'Change', only MainActivity's onConfigurationChanged called, Test's not called.
Here is the log:

```
D/MainActivity: screenChange

     --------- beginning of system
D/MainActivity: {1.0 ?mcc?mnc zh_CN ldltr sw360dp w640dp h335dp 320dpi nrml long land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.12 themeChanged=0 themeChangedFlags=0}
D/MainActivity: screenChange
D/MainActivity: {1.0 ?mcc?mnc zh_CN ldltr sw360dp w360dp h615dp 320dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.13 themeChanged=0 themeChangedFlags=0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the modify postion for this.
It is because of **extends AppCompatActivity**

But why?
and how to make AppCompatActivity invoke the onConfigurationChanged method correct.

Comment: here too - no idea why